What kind of socket is this?

I need to replace this tiny LED that backlights the Start button of some machinery.
I've been Googling around for a while but still no clue what type of lamp it is or how to find a replacement. Nothing useful in manufacturer's manual either.
Thanks in advance for any help.

The base is almost 100% likely to be unique to the switch manufacturer.
If you can't get a replacement from them then you can probably solder a new LED in place using the existing base (take care as to the polarity) or replace the entire switch.
